# Rails new flags, do "short flags" cover all indented options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

[image]

https://gist.github.com/kirillshevch/1b52f711e66b064416d746f07e834c00

For instance, does using capital S: `-S` skip all 3 of these?:

- sprockets
- sprint
- listen

Answer (score 0):

When you see a [list of options](https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/ace0222174804372b51a) like:

```
-S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]               # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring],  [--no-skip-spring]                  # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen],  [--no-skip-listen]                  # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
      [--skip-coffee],  [--no-skip-coffee]                  # Don't use CoffeeScript
```

It means:

- only `--skip-sprockets` has a short option equivalent `-S`
- all other options, like `--skip-spring` or even `--no-skip-sprockets`, must be used with their long form.